# Return children nodes of multiple parent nodes using Neo4j C# Client

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient

**Edited:**
 My graph contains two node types: PARENT and CHILD. The relationships can be PARENT<-PARENT, PARENT<-CHILD

First I'm getting all the titles of all the parents in the graph.

```
var query= client.Cypher
                 .Match("(parent:PARENT)")
                 .Return((parent) => parent.As<PARENT>().Title)
                 .Results.ToList();

    List<string> titlesofallParents= new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        titlesofallParents.Add(item);
    }
```

Then I'm trying to find all the children belonging to every node in the titlesofallParents list like this:

```
var q1= client.Cypher
          .Unwind(titlesofallParents,"titleItem")
          .Match("(p:PARENT{Title: titleItem})<-[*]-(u)")
          .Return((p, u) => new { R = p.As<Node<string>>(), N = u.As<Node<string>>()});
var results = q1.Results.ToList();
```

I'm trying to use unwind here to get the title of each row and then find it's children and return the result set of all rows on which we ran the query. If I do it with just one item in the list, it works. For more than one item in the list, I keep getting the exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Can anybody please suggest a proper approach here?

Comment: Do you get the null ref even for just 2 elements? And does every item in the list have a 'Child' or indeed - exists as a `PARENT`?

Comment: Also - what is `NodesList`? Are we talking an array of anonymous types here? or is the `Title: "Node1"` referring to an actual type?

Comment: @ChrisSkardon I changed it to a List<string> that contains just the Titles. The query works for more than one items in the list, but the output returns just one row of result. I'm expecting output in a format of a list for every query run against every 'Row'.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your actual code - I think I have what you have and it works as expected for me, so I just want to see what you're doing before I put an answer up..

Comment: @ChrisSkardon Edited the question